# Get the count of items in subcategories

Tags: mongodb

There is a tree of categories, such as

```
Mammalia-Rodentia...,
...,
Mammalia-Primates-Hominidae...,
Mammalia-Primates-Lemuridae...,
...
etc.
```

There is a set of categorized beings.

Given a category (e.g. Mammalia or Primates) how to calculate the number of beings in each subcategory:

```
{ Primates: 1098, Rodentia: 8932 }
```

or

```
{ Lemuridae: 129, Hominidae: 432 }
```

I'm trying to model Beings like this:

```
{
   name: "being #1",
   categories: [...,'Lemuridae', 'Primates', 'Mammalia']
}
```

To aggregate for e.g. Primates I {$match : {categories:'Primates'}}
then I need $project a category just before 'Primates' and it looks like this is impossible within aggregation framework... Thus either the model is incorrect or I have to use mapreduce...

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In order to count beings grouped by categories you need to first unwind categories field and then group.

The query doing this looks like that:

```
db.beings.aggregate(
  [
    { $unwind : '$categories' },
    { $group  : 
      { 
        _id:'$categories' , 
        count: { $sum : 1 } 
      } 
    }
  ]
);
```

Comment: This implies that I have first to query for the direct children of  the given category, then use this query with {$match: {_id: {$in: children} } } appended. Not bad. Thank you!